# Iterate Object containing instances of other objects

Tags: android, loops

I am looking for an elegant solution for a specific situation.
I have a JSON file
After I parse it, I get a class object the has fields that are instances of other objects. 
the class looks like this:

```
public class TaboolaResults {

@SerializedName("session")
@Expose
private String session;

@SerializedName("App-Below-Main-Column-Thumbnails-HP")
@Expose
private AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP;

@SerializedName("App-Below-Main-Column-Thumbnails-HP-2")
@Expose
private AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP2 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP2;

@SerializedName("App-Below-Main-Column-Thumbnails-HP-3")
@Expose
private AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP3 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP3;

@SerializedName("App-Below-Main-Column-Thumbnails-HP-4")
@Expose
private AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP4 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP4;

@SerializedName("App-Below-Main-Column-Thumbnails-HP-5")
@Expose
private AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP5 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP5;

@SerializedName("App-Below-Main-Column-Thumbnails-HP-6")
@Expose
private AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP6 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP6;

@SerializedName("App-Below-Main-Column-Thumbnails-HP-7")
@Expose
private AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP7 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP7;

@SerializedName("App-Below-Main-Column-Thumbnails-HP-8")
@Expose
private AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP8 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP8;

@SerializedName("App-Below-Main-Column-Thumbnails-HP-9")
@Expose
private AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP9 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP9;

public String getSession() {
    return session;
}

public void setSession(String session) {
    this.session = session;
}

public AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP getAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP() {
    return appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP;
}

public void setAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP(AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP) {
    this.appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP = appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP;
}

public AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP2 getAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP2() {
    return appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP2;
}

public void setAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP2(AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP2 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP2) {
    this.appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP2 = appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP2;
}

public AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP3 getAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP3() {
    return appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP3;
}

public void setAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP3(AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP3 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP3) {
    this.appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP3 = appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP3;
}

public AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP4 getAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP4() {
    return appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP4;
}

public void setAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP4(AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP4 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP4) {
    this.appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP4 = appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP4;
}

public AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP5 getAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP5() {
    return appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP5;
}

public void setAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP5(AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP5 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP5) {
    this.appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP5 = appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP5;
}

public AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP6 getAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP6() {
    return appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP6;
}

public void setAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP6(AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP6 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP6) {
    this.appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP6 = appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP6;
}

public AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP7 getAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP7() {
    return appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP7;
}

public void setAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP7(AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP7 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP7) {
    this.appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP7 = appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP7;
}

public AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP8 getAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP8() {
    return appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP8;
}

public void setAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP8(AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP8 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP8) {
    this.appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP8 = appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP8;
}

public AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP9 getAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP9() {
    return appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP9;
}

public void setAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP9(AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP9 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP9) {
    this.appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP9 = appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP9;
}
}
```

A very not elegant way that I achieved what I need is:

```
 private void extractTaboolaIntoFeed(final TaboolaResults results, final ArrayList<IFlexible> itemResults) {

    int i = 0;
    int currentTaboolaItem = 1;

    if (currentTaboolaItem <= mNumberOfTaboolaItems) {

        AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP = results.getAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP();

        for (; i < itemResults.size(); i++) {

            if (itemResults.get(i) instanceof AbstractItem) {

                AbstractItem abstractItem = (AbstractItem) itemResults.get(i);

                FeedItemType itemType = abstractItem.getItemType();
                if (itemType.equals(FeedItemType.TABOOLA)) {
                    mTaboolaDataSet.add(new TaboolaDataSetItem(abstractItem.getItemId(), appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP));
                    currentTaboolaItem++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (currentTaboolaItem <= mNumberOfTaboolaItems) {
        AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP2 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP2 = results.getAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP2();

        for (i++; i < itemResults.size(); i++) {
            if (itemResults.get(i) instanceof AbstractItem) {
                AbstractItem abstractItem = (AbstractItem) itemResults.get(i);
                FeedItemType itemType = abstractItem.getItemType();
                if (itemType.equals(FeedItemType.TABOOLA)) {
                    mTaboolaDataSet.add(new TaboolaDataSetItem(abstractItem.getItemId(), appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP2));
                    currentTaboolaItem++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (currentTaboolaItem <= mNumberOfTaboolaItems) {
        AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP3 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP3 = results.getAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP3();
        for (i++; i < itemResults.size(); i++) {
            if (itemResults.get(i) instanceof AbstractItem) {
                AbstractItem abstractItem = (AbstractItem) itemResults.get(i);
                FeedItemType itemType = abstractItem.getItemType();
                if (itemType.equals(FeedItemType.TABOOLA)) {
                    mTaboolaDataSet.add(new TaboolaDataSetItem(abstractItem.getItemId(), appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP3));
                    currentTaboolaItem++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (currentTaboolaItem <= mNumberOfTaboolaItems) {
        AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP4 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP4 = results.getAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP4();
        for (i++; i < itemResults.size(); i++) {

            if (itemResults.get(i) instanceof AbstractItem) {

                AbstractItem abstractItem = (AbstractItem) itemResults.get(i);
                FeedItemType itemType = abstractItem.getItemType();
                if (itemType.equals(FeedItemType.TABOOLA)) {
                    mTaboolaDataSet.add(new TaboolaDataSetItem(abstractItem.getItemId(), appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP4));
                    currentTaboolaItem++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (currentTaboolaItem <= mNumberOfTaboolaItems) {
        AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP5 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP5 = results.getAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP5();
        for (i++; i < itemResults.size(); i++) {

            if (itemResults.get(i) instanceof AbstractItem) {

                AbstractItem abstractItem = (AbstractItem) itemResults.get(i);
                FeedItemType itemType = abstractItem.getItemType();
                if (itemType.equals(FeedItemType.TABOOLA)) {
                    mTaboolaDataSet.add(new TaboolaDataSetItem(abstractItem.getItemId(), appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP5));
                    currentTaboolaItem++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (currentTaboolaItem <= mNumberOfTaboolaItems) {
        AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP6 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP6 = results.getAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP6();
        for (i++; i < itemResults.size(); i++) {
            if (itemResults.get(i) instanceof AbstractItem) {
                AbstractItem abstractItem = (AbstractItem) itemResults.get(i);
                FeedItemType itemType = abstractItem.getItemType();
                if (itemType.equals(FeedItemType.TABOOLA)) {
                    mTaboolaDataSet.add(new TaboolaDataSetItem(abstractItem.getItemId(), appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP6));
                    currentTaboolaItem++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (currentTaboolaItem <= mNumberOfTaboolaItems) {
        AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP7 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP7 = results.getAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP7();
        for (i++; i < itemResults.size(); i++) {
            if (itemResults.get(i) instanceof AbstractItem) {
                AbstractItem abstractItem = (AbstractItem) itemResults.get(i);
                FeedItemType itemType = abstractItem.getItemType();
                if (itemType.equals(FeedItemType.TABOOLA)) {
                    mTaboolaDataSet.add(new TaboolaDataSetItem(abstractItem.getItemId(), appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP7));
                    currentTaboolaItem++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (currentTaboolaItem <= mNumberOfTaboolaItems) {
        AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP8 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP8 = results.getAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP8();
        for (i++; i < itemResults.size(); i++) {
            if (itemResults.get(i) instanceof AbstractItem) {
                AbstractItem abstractItem = (AbstractItem) itemResults.get(i);
                FeedItemType itemType = abstractItem.getItemType();
                if (itemType.equals(FeedItemType.TABOOLA)) {
                    mTaboolaDataSet.add(new TaboolaDataSetItem(abstractItem.getItemId(), appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP8));
                    currentTaboolaItem++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (currentTaboolaItem <= mNumberOfTaboolaItems) {
        AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP9 appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP9 = results.getAppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP9();
        for (i++; i < itemResults.size(); i++) {
            if (itemResults.get(i) instanceof AbstractItem) {
                AbstractItem abstractItem = (AbstractItem) itemResults.get(i);
                FeedItemType itemType = abstractItem.getItemType();
                if (itemType.equals(FeedItemType.TABOOLA)) {
                    mTaboolaDataSet.add(new TaboolaDataSetItem(abstractItem.getItemId(), appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP9));
                    currentTaboolaItem++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm currently using gson to parse.
The result object containing the instances of the other object are the models received from gson.

Each time I parse the json, the class can contain a different number of objects, according to the response I get from the server.
So the goal is to iterate the fields of the class and check the class results, and check it has result objects or null.

Idily in theory:

Get the class object result, iterate all instance object results, and if object != null, do somethig.

Another possible solution if anybody knows if/how to accomplish it is to configure gson that even though the file contains different objects (objects with a different name), make gson create all objects the same as the equal objects with the same name.

Can anyone advise me a better way to do this?
Thank you

Comment: so maybe for such a thing `JsonReader` would be better?

Comment: you could use gson.

Comment: @pskink I'd rather use the Gson library parser.
But if that won't be possible, I'll definitely consider your solution.

Comment: @JunaidFahad I'm already using gson

Comment: Whats the difference between the classes' interfaces from AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP(0) to AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP9?

Comment: @mabvt classes interfaces?
Between AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP(0) to AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP9 there is no difference.
In reality, they are the same, with the same fields. 
They are only created for gson this way because of the json structure recieved in the response.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, what ` mNumberOfTaboolaItems` and `mTaboolaDataSet` are, but also show the class `TaboolaDataSetItem`? In addition, how the `AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP` -class instances look like finally? I fear that you have a huge logic error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up changing the class to:

```
public class TaboolaResults {

@SerializedName("session")
@Expose
private String session;

@SerializedName("App-Below-Main-Column-Thumbnails-HP")
@Expose
private AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP;

@SerializedName("App-Below-Main-Column-Thumbnails-HP-2")
@Expose
private AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP2;

@SerializedName("App-Below-Main-Column-Thumbnails-HP-3")
@Expose
private AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP3;

@SerializedName("App-Below-Main-Column-Thumbnails-HP-4")
@Expose
private AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP4;

@SerializedName("App-Below-Main-Column-Thumbnails-HP-5")
@Expose
private AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP5;

@SerializedName("App-Below-Main-Column-Thumbnails-HP-6")
@Expose
private AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP6;

@SerializedName("App-Below-Main-Column-Thumbnails-HP-7")
@Expose
private AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP7;

@SerializedName("App-Below-Main-Column-Thumbnails-HP-8")
@Expose
private AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP8;

@SerializedName("App-Below-Main-Column-Thumbnails-HP-9")
@Expose
private AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP appBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP9;
```

and simply iterate all results like this:

```
int currentTaboola = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < feedItems.size(); i++) {
            if (feedItems.get(i) instanceof TaboolaItem) {
                AbstractItem item = (AbstractItem) feedItems.get(i);
                AppBelowMainColumnThumbnailsHP taboolaResult = mGsonResults.getAppBelowMainColumnThumbnails(currentTaboola);
                mTaboolaDataSet.add(new TaboolaDataSetItem(item.getItemId(), taboolaResult));
                currentTaboola++;
            }
        }
```